# How to bind to array in angular 11

Tags: angular

How do i bind to an array in angular 11? My variable looks like

```js
const DISH = {
        id: '0',
        name: 'Uthappizza',
        image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        featured: true,
        label: 'Hot',
        price: '4.99',
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [{
            rating: 5,
            comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
            author: 'John Lemon',
            date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
        }],
}
```

I can bin then name like

```html
<h3>{{dish.name | uppercase}}</h3>
```

But how do i bind to the comments array?

Comment: why are there so many `<br />`s in the code? if this is an error, please remove them.

Comment: Sorry, after long time I forgot formating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the comments while using Angular's `*ngFor` loop, since it's an array (list) of comments. It's [described in the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) how you can use it, it's basically a for loop in your HTML. Every `item` within `dish.comments` gets looped over and `item.comment` (referring to `dish.comments.comment`) gets printed in the paragraph element.

```
<h3>{{ dish.name }}</h3>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of dish.comments">
    <p>{{ item.comment }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If there are more comments, they will show up in the list. See [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yyvzx5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for the code.